# Proof that sets $\mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B)$ are disjoint iff $A = B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to proof, that the two sets $\mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B)$ are disjoint if, and only if $A=B$, where $\bigtriangleup$ is the symmetrical difference and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the power set of $X$.

So one possible way to proof it, is by showing "$\rightarrow$" and "$\leftarrow$" individually.

I **think** I've got the "$\leftarrow$" part:

$\ A=B \\
\quad \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B) \space \land \space A \bigtriangleup B = \emptyset \\
\quad \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B) = \emptyset \space \land \space \mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B) = \{\emptyset \}\\
\quad \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B) \space \text{disjoint} \space \mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B)
$

But I don't know how to proof the "$\rightarrow$" part.

$\ \mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B) \space \text{disjoint} \space \mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B)\\
\quad \rightarrow (x \in \mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B) \rightarrow x \notin \mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B) \space \land \space x \in \mathcal{P}(A \bigtriangleup B) \rightarrow x \notin \mathcal{P}(A) \bigtriangleup \mathcal{P}(B))\\
\quad \rightarrow ???\\
\quad \rightarrow A=B
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to prove that $A\Delta B$ is empty.

Let's suppose the opposite, and for example let $x\in A\setminus B$. Then $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(A)\Delta\mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\{x\}\in\mathcal{P}(A\Delta B)$, so $\mathcal{P}(A)\Delta\mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A\Delta B)$ are not disjoint. The same argument applies if $x\in B\setminus A$.

Comment: I'm quite new to this kind of proofs, so it would be great if you could add some explanations :)

Comment: This is a proof by contradiction. Suppose what you want to prove is not true (in this case, suppose $A\ne B$) and try to reach a contradiction (in this case, I am concluding that $\mathcal{P}(A)\Delta\mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(A\Delta B)$ are not disjoint). To conclude the latter, I needed something that would belong to both of those, having in mind that something (call it $x$) is in one of the sets but not the other. The natural candidate was the one-element set $\{x\}$,  I tried it out and it worked!